# Backslash using for escaping qute regenerate after asigning String

Tags: c#, asp.net, backslash, htmltextwriter, stringwriter

in `ToString` methode of my Entity, i try to generate a informational string includes quotes. so i use backslash before quote and everything is good until i try to assign return value to a string variable and after that all  backslash comeback .here is the ToString function:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        string content = "{";
        content += "\"serviceType\":" + ServiceType.Name + ",";
        content += "\"Debt\":" + amount;
        content += "}";
        return content;
    }
```

after that i try to use `StringWriter` and `HtmlTextWriter` to generate a HTML but after assign the return value to a string variable there is a lot of `\`, `\r`, `\n`, `\t`in variable.here is the function:

```
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100%");
            writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "1px solid black");
            writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction, "rtl");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);// Begin Table

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
            writer.Write("زیر خدمت");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
            writer.Write(ServiceType.Name);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
            writer.Write("مبلغ");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
            writer.Write(amount);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderEndTag();// End Table
        }
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```

and after assigning the value to a variable:

```
<table style=\"width:100%;border-style:1px solid black;direction:rtl;\">\r\n\t<tr>\r\n\t\t<td>زیر خدمت</td><td>درمان</td>\r\n\t</tr><tr>\r\n\t\t<td>مبلغ</td><td>6000</td>\r\n\t</tr>\r\n</table>
```

what's happening here?

Comment: Hard to see "what's happening here" without showing some code

Comment: Let me check, coming back in short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That result seems ok to use in a webBrowser control inside C#. If you prefer to avoid these newlines and tabs (for a real browser), you can try replacing a few lines of your code like this.

OLD CODE:

```
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
```

NEW CODE:

```
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter, string.Empty))
    {
        writer.NewLine = string.Empty;
```

The second parameter in the HtmlTextWriter is the string used as tab.
So the result you get would be like:

```
<table style=\"width:100%;border-style:1px solid black;direction:rtl;\"><tr><td>زیر خدمت</td><td>درمان</td></tr><tr><td>مبلغ</td><td>6000</td></tr></table>
```

EDIT: In order to avoid the \" you could use `<? php echo` or `<%=`(for asp), or better rework the result as:

```
return stringWriter.ToString().Replace("\"", "'");
```

Comment: i use your sugesstion but i still have `\"` in my result But the other `\n`, `\t`, ... is gone

Comment: That should not be a problem. You could test it with any online tool, like [HTML And Script Code Tester](http://www.csgnetwork.com/htmlcodetest.html). Check this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/8AeqX3c.png)

Comment: i already check it but as you can see in you screenshot styles not applied to table.

Comment: You are right. Then I can only think of using `<?asp echo $return; ?>`. Let me check it and edit my answer